# How to compute the weight matrix for WLS estimation of a multi-group ordinal CFA model

Tags: r, factor-analysis, computational-statistics

I am attempting to perform a two-group confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) of one continuous factor on six ordinal predictors in `OpenMx` (`R`) using (robust) Weighted Least Squares (WLS) estimation. While I am completely new to OpenMx (I only used `sem` and `lavaan` ) I think I have most things now: I have a way of estimating polychoric correlations/covariances and estimating the latent means in one group and a good idea on how to implement this model in `OpenMx`.

I just have one problem, I need a weight matrix in WLS estimation. This should be an asymptotic covariance matrix of the elements of the observed correlations/covariances.

What is this exactly and how can I compute such a matrix?